Error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible' when calling Stored Procedure in MySQL
The Error says that Unable to cast object of type 'system.byte[] ' to type 'System.IConvertible' in the ExcecuteNonQuery(). What should I do? Anyone....
Details: HeidiSQL, and MySQL 5.0.96
 public Usuario Login(Usuario User)
 {
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SPLOGIN_USUARIO", MySqlConn); 
     MySqlTransaction Transaction = MySqlConn.BeginTransaction();
     cmd.Transaction = Transaction;
     
     try
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PIDUSUARIO", User.Id_Usuario);

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PPASSWORD", User.Contrasenia);

         //MySqlParameter mp = new MySqlParameter("PLOGIN", MySqlDbType.Bit);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@PLOGIN", MySqlDbType.Bit);
         cmd.Parameters["@PLOGIN"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
         
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@PMSG", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
         cmd.Parameters["@PMSG"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         Transaction.Commit();

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         try { }//Transaction.Rollback(); }
         catch { };
         throw e;
     }
     finally
     {
         cmd.Dispose();
     }
     return User;
 }


It is not looks as mysql error. It's looks as you application error
